# Erro no código, C

Tags: c

Eu criei um código extremamente simples apenas para testar o `Code::Blocks`, mas não importa o que eu faça, sempre retorna o seguinte erro:

```
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

ainda não entendi no que estou errando. o código vai aqui:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){
   int A;
   printf("Digite um valor: ");
   scanf("%d", &A);
   printf("O valor digitado foi: ", &A);
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Essa mensagem nada tem haver com o código, ele é perfeitamente compilável (embora não faça o que você quer, como visto na resposta do dvm). Há algum problema com o seu compilador. Você tem certeza de que essa é a **única** mensagem mostrada? Bem provável que tenha algumas antes dela explicando o que aconteceu.

Answer (score 3):

O erro do programa esta na seguinte linha:

```
   printf("O valor digitado foi: ", &A);
```

Correto:

```
   printf("O valor digitado foi: %d", A);
```

Repare que para se referenciar a uma variável e exibi-la na tela, é necessário utilizar o '%d' dentro da frase e, após a virgula, NÃO é necessário utilizar o caractere '&' (este só é necessário para referenciação no 'scanf').

Answer (score 1):

Você possui um erro relacionado à linha do printf, deveria estar escrito da seguinte forma:

```
printf("O valor digitado foi: %d\n", A);
```

A variável A no caso do `scanf` é passada como referência para que o mesmo possa alterá-la, já no `printf` é apenas informada para que possa exibir o conteúdo desta.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>                      ^^
> ```

`ld` é o "linker": a parte do compilador que 'mistura' o teu código com o código já existente (o do `scanf()`, por exemplo).

Tirando o `&A` usado no `printf()`, que devia ser apenas `a`, o teu programa não tem erro. Este erro não impede a compilação, mas os resultados serão estranhos.

Verifica a configuração do teu compilador, principalmente a parte do linker, os caminhos para bibliotecas, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Coisas para considerar:

1. Ausência de checagem de input: Nada garante que um "int" será
   digitado em stdin
2. Ausência de checagem do scanf: Nada garante que o inteiro
   recebido será "suficiente" para abrigar o mesmo em um dado do tipo
   "int"
3. Falta de espaçamento: É interessante que todas as mensagens no
   console possuam pelo menos uma quebra de linha (\n)
4. Ausência de formatação: Todo parâmetro passado para printf precisa possuir
   um especificador de acordo com o tipo da variável (%d, %p , %i ....)
5. Representação incorreta do valor armazenado por A: Usar &A em
   printf irá passar o "endereço de memória" que o valor de A reside:

**(Endereço)**
`printf("Valor: %p\n",&A)`

**(Valor)**
`printf("Valor: %d\n",A)`

Caso seja um problema específico no processo de compilação, você pode passar um "-v" para deduzir o que seja.